# Generic function with parameters of function passed as a parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to implement a small caching function. While my implementation appears to work, I'm having a hard time defining the proper types in it.

```
type Producer<T> = (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>;

export function cache<T>(producer: Producer<T>): Producer<T> {
  let cached;
  return async function(...args: any[]): Promise<T> {
    if (!cached) {
      cached = await producer.apply(null, args);
    }
    return cached;
  };
}
```

Yes, I still have to improve it, so that the value is cached based on the passed parameters, but that's a minor and easy to fix issue.

a `Producer` in this case is a function that can produce a cacheable value and should only ever be called once. `cache()` returns a function that should have matching parameters to the producer passed to the `cache()` function. Now, this works perfectly fine right now if you know what parameters to pass, but this is TypeScript, so I would love the compiler to be able to validate the types. I just don't know how to define that the returned function should have the same parameters as the producer. I know that there are all these utility types in TS, but I cannot figure out how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) utility to extract type of arguments of the producer function:

```
function cache<T, TProducer extends Producer<T>>(producer: TProducer): TProducer {
  let cached: Promise<T>;
  const wrapper = (...args: Parameters<TProducer>): Promise<T> => {
    if (!cached) {
      cached = producer(...args);
    }
    return cached;
  };

  return wrapper as TProducer;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGE4B4AqA+KAXigAoA6CgQzgHMBnALikoDsQBtAXQEoiD4EAWwCWdCLjwBuAFDSAZihZpgwhCyhpKaABbicAGig4BqDHCgQAHsAgskdWIlOYJeEmCfpMTY57PcfEy9zAG9pKCgAGwhgDS1dJCYBETEJGQi0NTpYgHc4SjBIc2JyKlpGWGpKQRjMOlwgszwAxyFRPQJCAjCIiOE5UgBCTR0IJF4e3oz4saIoD2Rg0rJqem503oBfcN64GJQ4dRGEjc2ZHb3gA-U8gqLmB19Fsxlt+UVlVXU5BAQSSiYLBQggARphDCCmNk4MIWDQWsl2lggaDMN0LvtDq0UhAyHs6AhIgA3CAkACM62kb0yLGycVGSDmx1JPwQlOkzKQ5MMAHIAEw87hkYC6FgkYoEGkE6JkSIIGji7jrIA)

---

Comment: while your solution doesn't crash, it also doesn't solve the problem. now If I define `const x = cache((param: String) => param);` and try to call it with a wrong parameter like `x(4)`, the compiler still doesn't complain

Comment: Actually it does https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGE4B4AqA+KAXigAoA6CgQzgHMBnALikoDsQBtAXQEoiD4EAWwCWdCLjwBuAFDSIADzAI4wKADMULNMGEIWUNJTQALcTgA0UHANQY4UBcAgskdWIluYJeEmA-pMJmt-O24GaShSCjJqeiYYakpBCCc4OlwbALg8XkJ+RBExCSgAbwioABsUgyNTJCCZSLgUlDh9SjoQLXVNbV19cipaRlhE5NT04OQsnPiC0TMCMsjI4TVSAEJDEwgkXmWVyO26omYAd0phVT9puxiwMAqQEhYUCorLWLpuRpWAX3KTRabRqOyQvz+MgB0jQejoqnkp2OEBIvjGTHhcGELBouXyQgWZGadAQFQAbiiwGNuD9pPISAAWbhAA

Comment: The only problem with previous approach was that return type of cached function wasn't properly inferred. Please check updated version

Comment: now it worked like a charm! Thank you! I am totally confused about how to interpret this and I will need some time for it to sink in, but it definitely solves my problem!

Comment: Let me know if you need explanation for any part of above solution

Comment: I'm good. I got it. But I wouldn't have come up with TProducer myself